# How can you tell how many MBs a sql query is returning?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm running a SQL query that is taking at least 7 seconds to return.  I'm wondering if there is a way to determine how many MBs that SQL is returning.  I'm trying to figure out how much time it is taking to do the actual query vs how much time is spent with transferring the results from the server.

It is a simple sql query, something like:

```
select * from Table where this = 'that'
```

Comment: I think this question is related to the other one you posted. You probably are not concerned about the MBs returned, but about the execution time. Please post the exact query and its execution plan. If you don't know how to get the plan, just ask.